# Websocket - new instance for every connection?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I followed the example here to setup a websocket server.
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-server-api.html

```
public class MySocketCreator implements WebSocketCreator {
    private MyEchoSocket mySocket;

    @Inject
    public MyAdvancedEchoCreator(MyEchoSocket mySocket) {
        this.mySocket = mySocket;
    }

    @Override
    public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest req, ServletUpgradeResponse resp) {
        return mySocket;
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that:

1. I'm wondering if the MyEchoSocket is a @Singleton?
2. Since MyEchoSocket looks something like this:

   ```
    @WebSocket(maxTextMessageSize = 64 * 1024)
    public class MyEchoSocket {

       private final CountDownLatch closeLatch;

       private Set<Session> session;

       public MyEchoSocket() {
           sessionList = new ArrayList<>();
       }

      @OnWebSocketClose
       public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
          ....
       }

       @OnWebSocketConnect
       public void onConnect(Session session) {
           sessionList.add(session);
       }

       @OnWebSocketMessage
       public void onMessage(String msg) {
           ....
       }
   }
   ```

The problem I'm running into is that the when a number of different clients are connected, and one goes offline, I have no clue as to which client went offline.
Or am I doing this wrong and that for each new client I get a new instance of: MyEchoSocket
which I use to keep track of the session?